# Inserting data to many-to-many relationship with payload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, crud

So I have this basic entity model:

[image: Entity model]

The relationship between `Stations` and `Timetables` is many-to-many, and the linking table also has a payload `Arrival` and `Departure`. What I'm trying to create is a `Create` page for timetables that will insert the relevant data.

So far, I've created the following view model:

```
public class TimetablesCreateViewModel
{
    public Timetable Timetable { get; set; }

    public StationTimetable StationTimetable { get; set; }

    public Station Station { get; set; }

    public SelectList StationList { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm using it in my `TimetablesController`'s `Create` action like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TimetablesCreateViewModel model = new TimetablesCreateViewModel
    {
        Timetable = new Timetable(),
        StationList = new SelectList(db.Stations, "Id", "Name")
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

then, in my view, I'm generating the form input for stations by simply looping 10 times:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Station</th>
        <th>Arrival Time</th>
        <th>Departure Time</th>
    </tr>

    @for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StationTimetable, Model.StationList, "---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StationTimetable.Arrival, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StationTimetable.Departure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I browse to the page, the form is generated and it *looks* like what I want, however when I populate it and submit the form, I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'StationTimetable'.

I'm not too concerned with the exception, what I'm most concerned with is how the form is being generated in the HTML. There are a lot of duplicate `name` attributes for the input elements, and it really seems like I took a wrong turn when implementing this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I fixed the exception by specifying `model => model.StationTimetable.StationId` in the `DropDownListFor` call, however when I submit the form the proper `Timetable` entry gets created but the `StationTimetables` data does not. Any ideas?

Comment: I have addressed the duplicate name attribute issue (and how to create and post back a collection) in my answer to your next question, but the error message is due to the fact that property `StationList` is `null`. Since you appear to be assigning it in the GET method, the most likely its because you return the view in the POST method and have not reassigned the property again - i.e.  `StationList = new SelectList(db.Stations, "Id", "Name"); return View(model);`

Answer (score 0):

Look, in your Controller you are creating a new object of type TimetablesCreateViewModel and then you are sending it to the view. In your view, you are looping around what exactly? A one object? If you want to loop like this, you should create a list of objects of type TimetablesCreateViewModel and send it to the view.

Comment: If I create multiple `TimetablesCreateViewModel`'s in my view will that not create multiple `Timetable` entries when I mean to create one `Timetable` entry and have multiple `StationTimetable` entries? I think I might know what you're getting at though, so I'll hack away at that for a bit.